# rails faux active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use faux active record (a model that has no persistence in db).

I followed this example:
https://quickleft.com/blog/using-faux-activerecord-models-in-rails-3/

And I have this error:

ArgumentError in SearchController#new
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

app/models/search.rb:32:in `assign_attributes'
app/models/search.rb:27:in`initialize'
app/controllers/search_controller.rb:4:in `new'
app/controllers/search_controller.rb:4:in`new'

It seems that when you call Search.new it needs the parametters but my goal is to make it an empty Search object.

Here are my model, controller, view, route:

**Model**

```
    class Search

  include ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity

  TRUE_VALUES = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::TRUE_VALUES

  attr_accessor :query
  attr_reader :safe_search, :results_per_page

  alias_method :safe_search?, :safe_search

  attr_accessible :query, :safe_search, :results_per_page

  RESULTS_PER_PAGE = [10, 25, 50, 100].freeze

  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates :query, presence: true
  validates :results_per_page, presence: true, inclusion: { in: RESULTS_PER_PAGE }

  def persisted?
    false
  end  

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    assign_attributes(attributes)
    yield(self) if block_given?
  end

  def assign_attributes(values, options = {})
    sanitize_for_mass_assignment(values, options[:as]).each do |k, v|
      send("#{k}=", v)
    end
  end

  def results_per_page=(value)
    @results_per_page = value.to_i
  end

  def safe_search=(value)
    @safe_search = TRUE_VALUES.include?(value)
  end

end
```

**Controller**

```
    class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @search = Search.new
    render "search/new.html.erb"
  end

  def create
    @search = Search.new(params[:search])

    # TODO: use the @search object to perform a search.  Adding
    # a `results` method on the search object might be a good starting point.
  end

end
```

**View: search/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @search do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :query %>
  <%= f.text_field :query %>

  <%= f.label :safe_search %>
  <%= f.check_box :safe_search  %>

  <%= f.label :results_per_page %>
  <%= f.select_box :results_per_page  %>

<%= end %>
```

Comment: Why are you are trying to override the Rails `assign_attributes` method (doc [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/assign_attributes))?  That seems to be related to your error.

Comment: Hi Steve, I think the author uses that because it is not an ordinary active record object.

Comment: I commented the assign_attributes and initialize just to see if it works now i am having this error from the view: undefined method `searches_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fca6a4249d8>:0x007fca6a4229f8>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for @search do |f| %>
2: 
3:   <%= f.label :query %>
4:   <%= f.text_field :query %>   . I am updating my question with the route that i am using.

Comment: here is my route: match 'search/new', to: 'search#new', :via => :get

Comment: Here is how i made it work:

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I found:
In the model I am using this:

```
  def initialize(attributes = {})
      assign_attributes(attributes)
  end

  def assign_attributes(attributes)
    sanitize_for_mass_assignment(attributes).each do |k, v|
      send("#{k}=", v)
    end
  end
```

Here are my new and create methods in the controller:

```
  def new
    @search = Search.new
    render "search/new.html.erb"
  end

  def create
    @search = Search.new(params[:search])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :template => "search/create.html.erb" }
    end 
  end
```

By the way i had to rename my controller to SearchesController because controllers must be pluralized.

And here is my new.html.erb view:

```
<%= form_for @search, url: { action: "create" }, :method => :post do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :query %>
  <%= f.text_field :query %>

  <%= f.label :safe_search %>
  <%= f.check_box :safe_search  %>

  <%= f.label :results_per_page %>
  <%= f.select(:results_per_page, [10, 25, 50, 100])  %>

  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

I hope this will be useful to somebody.